# ErrorException Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel, sql, querybuilder

Tengo la siguiente consulta, les explico:

$id captura el id del usuario logueado (creo que esto esta demás explicarlo)
$empresa captura los datos de la empresa de la persona que esta logueada.
$id_empresa captura solo el id_empresa de la tabla users (alli la deje)
$clientes trae todos los clientes de esa empresa.

```
$id = Auth()->id();
        $empresa = DB::select('select * from empresa where id='.$id);
        $id_empresa = DB::select('select id_empresa from users where id='.$id);
        $clientes = DB::table('cliente as cli')
                        ->join('credito as cre','cre.id_cliente','cli.id')
                        ->join('cobrador as co','co.id','cre.id_cobrador')
                        ->join('lugares as lu','lu.id','cli.id_lugar')
                        ->select('cli.id', 'cli.nombre','cli.telefono','cli.dpi','cli.id_lugar','cli.direccion','lu.departamento','lu.municipio')
                        ->where('id_empresa','=',$id_empresa)
                        ->groupBy('cli.id', 'cli.nombre','cli.telefono','cli.dpi','cli.id_lugar','cli.direccion','lu.departamento','lu.municipio')
                        ->get();
        return view('Clientes.index', compact('clientes'));
```

el problema es que en el query clientes cuando coloco $id_empresa en el where me da el error que estoy posteando, pero si le pongo el numero 1 funciona todo bien. como podré corregir este error?

PD: cuando me sale el error intento hacer un dd(clientes) y siempre me sale el error y no me muestra que es lo que trae el query.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está sucediendo es que esta consulta está retornando un `array` de objetos `stdClass`:

```
$id_empresa = DB::select('select id_empresa from users where id='.$id);
```

Y estás enviando dicho array a un cláusula `where()` y eso genera el error.

Lo que tú buscas es obtener un sólo valor con el id de la empresa, por ello te recomiendo utilizar `DB::table()`.

```
$id_empresa = DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->pluck('id_empresa');
```

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::pluck() me aparece esto @L. Flor

Comment: Gracias @L. Flor me has ayudado (en mas de una ocasion) esta respuesta me ayudo "$id_empresa = DB::table(users)->select('id_empresa')->whereId($id)->value('id');" podrías explicarme algo sobre como funciona el WhereId($id)->value('id'). Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El fallo comienza desde esta consulta:

```
 $id_empresa = DB::select('select id_empresa from users where id='.$id);
```

Que te retornaría una salida como esta:

```
>>> $data = \DB::select("select id_empresa from users where id = algo");
=> [
     {#3313
       +"id_empresa": 1,
       +"name": "algo",
       +"created_at": "2020-11-11 15:05:33",
       +"updated_at": "2020-11-11 15:05:33",
     },
   ]
>>>
```

Esto claramente no te va a servir tal cual esta como valor para usarlo en la condición del `WHERE`, lo que tendrías que hacer lo siguiente para poder acceder al valor deseado:

```
$id_empresa[0]->id_empresa;
```

Entonces puedes modificarla del modo siguiente:

```
 $id_empresa = DB::table(users)->whereId($id)->value('id_empresa');
```

Usar el método [value](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table) nos ayuda a solo obtener un valor en lugar de una fila completa, lo cual lleva a que esta variable: **`$id_empresa`** ahora si la puedas ocupar en la condición.

La salida tanto para first como para value son las siguientes:

```
>>> $data = \DB::table('users')->select('id_empresa')->whereId(1)->first();
=> {#3290
     +"id": 1,
   }
>>> $data = \DB::table('users')->whereId(1)->value('id_empresa');
=> 1
>>>
```

Comment: podrias ayudarme a saber como funciona esto exactamente? WhereId($id)->value('id')

Comment: gracias, ahora lo comprendo mejor. te lo agradezco bastante. no sabia que podia usar ese WhereId o WhereIdEmpresa. Todos los dias aprende algo nuevo uno. :)

Comment: si voté la respuesta.

Comment: borraste tu comentario sobre la explicación de la consulta?

Comment: podrías explicarme como hacer eso pero con un DB::select() ?